# How to add custom attributes to an AAD user and include it the JWT token sent to the client application?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to create an AAD App Registration that includes additional claims in the JWT tokens that are returned to the client application.

The idea is that a SalesRepID fields need to be added to each of the AAD users. Then the SalesRepID be included in JWT claims through application manifest configuration.

Is this possible? What are the steps? An article or a code sample that shows how to do this would be a great help?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

1) Add custom attribute by using [Register an extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#register-an-extension--). (Please note that it only supports v1.0 application)

2) Set values for custom attributes.

3) Modify application manifest of the Azure AD application and return the extension property as claims.

Besides, Microsoft strongly recommends that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources. For how to add custom attribute to Azure AD user with Microsoft Graph API, please refer to: [Add custom data to users using open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users#1-add-roaming-profile-information).

Comment: Hi @AllanXu, has this issue been resolved? If there is anything unclear, you could add more details.